# Switching between 2 cameras (using opencv)

Tags: python, opencv, cameras, ros-noetic, frames

I have a manipulator in ROS and 2 cameras attached on it.
I want to switch the frames of cameras every 5 seconds
Both cameras work fine.
I do not want to close the window and reopen it (if it is possible). I just want to switch the frames of cameras in the same window.
So far, the first camera shows me its frame, but after 5 seconds, the frame sticks.

How can I fix this problem?

Below is my code:

```
import cv2
import rospy
import time
from cv_bridge import CvBridge, CvBridgeError
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image

front_camera_enabled = True
bottom_camera_enabled = False
window_name = "CAMERA"

def scan_target_callback(data):
    global front_camera_enabled, bottom_camera_enabled
    if bottom_camera_enabled:
        try:
            cv2.namedWindow(window_name, cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
            cv2.resizeWindow(window_name, 640, 480)
            bridge = CvBridge()
            cv_image = bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(data, desired_encoding="bgr8")
            cv2.imshow(window_name, cv_image)
            cv2.waitKey(1)
        except CvBridgeError as e:
            print("Error in converting image from bottom camera")
            rospy.logerr(e)

def ur3_camera_callback(data):
    global front_camera_enabled, bottom_camera_enabled
    if front_camera_enabled:
        try:
            cv2.namedWindow(window_name, cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
            cv2.resizeWindow(window_name, 640, 480)
            bridge = CvBridge()
            cv_image = bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(data, desired_encoding="bgr8")
            cv2.imshow(window_name, cv_image)
            cv2.waitKey(1)
        except CvBridgeError as e:
            print("Error in converting image from front camera")
            rospy.logerr(e)




def timer_callback(event):
    global front_camera_enabled, bottom_camera_enabled
    front_camera_enabled = not front_camera_enabled
    bottom_camera_enabled = not bottom_camera_enabled
    print("SWITCH CAMERA")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    rospy.init_node("husky_ur3")

    rospy.Subscriber("/g_d435/rgb/g_image_raw", Image, ur3_camera_callback)
    rospy.Subscriber("/g_d435_down/rgb/g_image_raw_down", Image, scan_target_callback)

    rospy.Timer(rospy.Duration(5.0), timer_callback)

    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        print("BOTTOM CAM: "+str(bottom_camera_enabled) + "      FRONT CAM: "+str(front_camera_enabled))

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange!

It would be better to share more information about the underlying use case, as it is unsure what you are trying to achieve. Nevertheless, it seems that you need both images simultaneously, where image processing keeps switching on a timely basis. This can be achieved by [message_filters](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters). Please see below a demo code:

```
import sys
import rospy
import cv2
import message_filters
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image
from cv_bridge import CvBridge, CvBridgeError


class ImageSwitchingNode:
    def __init__(self):
        self.switch_image = True
        self.image_switch_timer = rospy.Timer(rospy.Duration(5.0), self.timer_callback)

        self.bridge = CvBridge()
        self.image_rviz_sub = message_filters.Subscriber('/rviz_node/image_raw', Image)
        self.image_turtlesim_sub = message_filters.Subscriber('/turtlesim_node/image_raw', Image)
        self.time_sync = message_filters.ApproximateTimeSynchronizer([self.image_rviz_sub, self.image_turtlesim_sub], 10, 0.1)
        self.time_sync.registerCallback(self.sync_callback)

    def timer_callback(self, event):
        self.switch_image = not self.switch_image

    def sync_callback(self, image_rviz_msg, image_turtlesim_msg):
        try:
            image_rviz = self.bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(image_rviz_msg, 'bgr8')
            image_turtlesim = self.bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(image_turtlesim_msg, 'bgr8')
        except CvBridgeError as err:
            rospy.logerr(err)

        image = image_rviz if self.switch_image else image_turtlesim
        cv2.imshow('Camera', image)
        cv2.waitKey(1)


def main(args):
    rospy.init_node('image_switching_node')
    image_switching_node = ImageSwitchingNode()
    try:
        rospy.spin()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        rospy.loginfo('Shutting down')
    finally:
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

Below are the steps, I used for executing it:

```
$ roscore
$ rosrun image_publisher image_publisher /opt/ros/noetic/share/turtlesim/images/noetic.png __name:=turtlesim_node
$ rosrun image_publisher image_publisher /opt/ros/noetic/share/rviz/images/splash.png __name:=rviz_node
$ rosrun my_pkg above_code.py
```

I am attaching a video of the output below:

[image: Screen Recording]

Hope it helps!

Comment: Most of your changes are an improvement, but 1) the synchronization is unnecessary (and since we don't know the image frame rate it may actually break things), and 2) calling `imgmsg_to_cv2()` and then throwing away the result seems wasteful of cpu.

Comment: @Mike973: I agree with you. Basically, the `imgmsg_to_cv2` can be called selectively based on the flag. Regardless, as said earlier, the underlying use case is unknown, and there are many ways to deal with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and now it works every single time.
Code does not use any ApproximateTimeSynchronizer function.

```
import sys
import rospy
import cv2
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image
from cv_bridge import CvBridge, CvBridgeError

class ImageSwitchingNode:
    def __init__(self):
        self.switch_image = True
        self.bridge = CvBridge()

        self.image_rviz_sub = rospy.Subscriber('/g_d435/rgb/g_image_raw', Image,self.image_rviz_callback, queue_size=1)
        self.image_turtlesim_sub = rospy.Subscriber('/g_d435_down/rgb/g_image_raw_down', Image, self.image_turtlesim_callback, queue_size=1)

        self.timer_switch = rospy.Timer(rospy.Duration(5.0), self.timer_callback)
        self.timer_display = rospy.Timer(rospy.Duration(0.1), self.display_callback)

        self.image_rviz = None
        self.image_turtlesim = None

def timer_callback(self, event):
    self.switch_image = not self.switch_image

def image_rviz_callback(self, msg):
    try:
        self.image_rviz = self.bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(msg, 'bgr8')
    except CvBridgeError as err:
        rospy.logerr(err)

def image_turtlesim_callback(self, msg):
    try:
        self.image_turtlesim = self.bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(msg, 'bgr8')
    except CvBridgeError as err:
        rospy.logerr(err)

def display_callback(self, event):
    if self.switch_image:
        image = self.image_rviz
    else:
        image = self.image_turtlesim

    if image is not None:
        cv2.imshow('Camera', image)
        cv2.waitKey(1)

def main(args):
    rospy.init_node('image_switching_node')
    image_switching_node = ImageSwitchingNode()

    try:
        rospy.spin()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        rospy.loginfo('Shutting down')
    finally:
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```